ASP .NET core API error code 400 when trying to do a PUT
I have a .Net API with EF core, i generated the endpoints automatically from the models. Now i have a problem with the put method. when i send my model to the API i get a error 500 response back, when i try it within Swaggers i get an error 400 response. I feel that there's something wrong with the way i setup my models but i can't figure out what it exactly is.
API:
group.MapPut("/{id}", async Task<Results<Ok, NotFound>> (int id, User user, DataContext db) =>
{
    var affected = await db.User
        .Where(model => model.Id == id)
        .ExecuteUpdateAsync(setters => setters
            .SetProperty(m => m.Id, user.Id)
            .SetProperty(m => m.Name, user.Name)
            .SetProperty(m => m.Company, user.Company)
            .SetProperty(m => m.Department, user.Department)
            .SetProperty(m => m.Email, user.Email)
            .SetProperty(m => m.Password, user.Password)
            );
    return affected == 1 ? TypedResults.Ok() : TypedResults.NotFound();
})
.WithName("UpdateUser")
.WithOpenApi();

Front-end:
@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [SupplyParameterFromForm]
    public User? user { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (Id != null)
        {
            try{
                var response = await HttpClient.GetAsync($"https://localhost:7183/api/User/{Id}");
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                user = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(json, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle error
                Console.WriteLine("Error getting user: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            user ??= new();
        }
    }

    void AddUser()
    {
        if (Id != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7183/api/User");

                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(user);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = client.PutAsync($"User/{Id}", content).Result;

                NavManager.NavigateTo("/UserOverview");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle error
                Console.WriteLine("Error adding user: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] salt = GenerateSalt();
                user.Password = HashPassword(user.Password, salt);

                var client = new HttpClient();
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7183/api/User");

                var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(user);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var response = client.PostAsync("User", content).Result;

                NavManager.NavigateTo("/UserOverview");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Handle error
                Console.WriteLine("Error adding user: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private string HashPassword(string password, byte[] salt)
    {
        using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, salt, 10000))
        {
            byte[] hash = pbkdf2.GetBytes(32); // 32 bytes for SHA256
            byte[] hashBytes = new byte[36]; // 32 bytes for hash + 4 bytes for salt

            Array.Copy(salt, 0, hashBytes, 0, 4);
            Array.Copy(hash, 0, hashBytes, 4, 32);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);
        }
    }

    private byte[] GenerateSalt()
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[4]; // 4 bytes for salt
        using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rngCsp.GetBytes(salt);
        }
        return salt;
    }
}

Model
namespace CalibrationReportingToolApi.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }   
        public string Password { get; set; }

        // Relationships
        public ICollection<MachineNote> Notes { get; set; }
        public ICollection<MachineMaintenance> Maintenances { get; set; }
        public ICollection<KnoopCallibratiobIndirect> KnoopCallibratiobIndirects { get; set; }
        public ICollection<VickersCallibrationIndirect> VickersCallibrationIndirects { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BrinellCallibrationIndirect> BrinellCallibrationIndirects { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RockwellCallibrationIndirect> RockwellCallibrationIndirects { get; set;}
        public ICollection<VickersCallibrationDirect> VickersCallibrationDirects { get; set; }
        public ICollection<BrinellCallibrationDirect> BrinellCallibrationDirects { get; set; }
        public ICollection<RockwellCallibrationDirect> RockwellCallibrationDirects { get; set; }
    }
}

Error 400 response from Swagger:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Failed to read parameter "User user" from the request body as JSON.
 ---> System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to CalibrationReportingToolApi.Models.KnoopCallibratiobIndirect. Path: $.notes[0].machine.knoopCallibratiobIndirects[0] | LineNumber: 28 | BytePositionInLine: 18.
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_DeserializeUnableToConvertValue(Type propertyType)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value, Boolean& isPopulatedValue)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, TCollection& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value, Boolean& isPopulatedValue)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value, Boolean& isPopulatedValue)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value, Boolean& isPopulatedValue)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonCollectionConverter`2.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, TCollection& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value, Boolean& isPopulatedValue)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonPropertyInfo`1.ReadJsonAndSetMember(Object obj, ReadStack& state, Utf8JsonReader& reader)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryRead(Utf8JsonReader& reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state, T& value, Boolean& isPopulatedValue)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.ContinueDeserialize(ReadBufferState& bufferState, JsonReaderState& jsonReaderState, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.DeserializeAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Metadata.JsonTypeInfo`1.DeserializeAsObjectAsync(Stream utf8Json, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequestJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync(HttpRequest request, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequestJsonExtensions.ReadFromJsonAsync(HttpRequest request, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegateForJson>g__TryReadBodyAsync|102_0(HttpContext httpContext, Type bodyType, String parameterTypeName, String parameterName, Boolean allowEmptyRequestBody, Boolean throwOnBadRequest, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.Log.InvalidJsonRequestBody(HttpContext httpContext, String parameterTypeName, String parameterName, Exception exception, Boolean shouldThrow)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegateForJson>g__TryReadBodyAsync|102_0(HttpContext httpContext, Type bodyType, String parameterTypeName, String parameterName, Boolean allowEmptyRequestBody, Boolean throwOnBadRequest, JsonTypeInfo jsonTypeInfo)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass102_2.<<HandleRequestBodyAndCompileRequestDelegateForJson>b__2>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:7183
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.WhNuX7sAGOE=CfDJ8BSIRFuoO3BNpdEx-GB1aMcdvJDP7YxmucuQ8GK_ggdu-Cj8qFYX6LsU-VMaW9feKIgkzw4suXMgBY5VvRdONih2w63wFiJR8W98Zerh9Sn3rsc-ezGGkx9s7jplxqic3WG-tWQASGdc7aXMIwUl12g
Origin: https://localhost:7183
Referer: https://localhost:7183/swagger/index.html
Content-Length: 32469
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="124", "Google Chrome";v="124", "Not-A.Brand";v="99"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
priority: u=1, i

content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
 date: Wed,08 May 2024 07:42:15 GMT 
 server: Kestrel 

What i send to the API via Swagger (bit shorter otherwise it's to long for Stackoverflow):
curl -X 'PUT' \
  'https://localhost:7183/api/User/1' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "test",
  "company": "test",
  "department": "test",
  "email": "test",
  "password": "test",
  "notes": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string",
      "description": "string",
      "dateTime": "2024-05-08T09:08:25.405Z",
      "machineId": 0,
      "userId": 0,
      "machine": {
        "id": 0,
        "description": "string",
        "type": "string",
        "serialNumber": "string",
        "microscopeType": "string",
        "microscopeSerialNumber": "string",
        "yearOfManufacture": 0,
        "manufacturer": "string",
        "condition": "string",
        "endUser": "string",
        "ukas": true,
        "knoopCallibratiobIndirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "vickersCallibrationIndirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "brinellCallibrationIndirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "rockwellCallibrationIndirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "vickersCallibrationDirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "brinellCallibrationDirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "rockwellCallibrationDirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "machineNotes": [
          "string"
        ],
        "machineMaintenances": [
          "string"
        ]
      },
      "user": "string"
    }
  ],
  "maintenances": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "dateTime": "2024-05-08T09:08:25.406Z",
      "machineId": 0,
      "userId": 0,
      "machine": {
        "id": 0,
        "description": "string",
        "type": "string",
        "serialNumber": "string",
        "microscopeType": "string",
        "microscopeSerialNumber": "string",
        "yearOfManufacture": 0,
        "manufacturer": "string",
        "condition": "string",
        "endUser": "string",
        "ukas": true,
        "knoopCallibratiobIndirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "vickersCallibrationIndirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "brinellCallibrationIndirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "rockwellCallibrationIndirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "vickersCallibrationDirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "brinellCallibrationDirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "rockwellCallibrationDirects": [
          "string"
        ],
        "machineNotes": [
          "string"
        ],
        "machineMaintenances": [
          "string"
        ]
      },
      "user": "string",
      "taskDone": [
        {
          "machineMaintenanceId": 0,
          "maintenanceTaskId": 0,
          "machineMaintenance": "string",
          "maintenanceTask": {
            "id": 0,
            "description": "string",
            "valid": true,
            "taskDone": [
              "string"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],

I tested my other API endpoints (get, add , delete)these seem to be in a working condition

Can you share the request body that is sent to API as snippet? Thanks.

look at the latest edit :)

Ya, the KnoopCallibratiobIndirects property expects an array of KnoopCallibratiobIndirect array, but you are providing the value with an array of strings. The same goes for those properties with the ICollection type. You should think that those properties are required or not when providing the JSON body from the front-end. If not, you should omit passing value for those fields or you should create an DTO class with the properties that are needed.

thx i'll try that later this week
